# Why am I getting 100% accuracy for SVM and Decision Tree (scikit)

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with 1175 examples and 21 features which are in the range of [-1, +1], and two class labels 1 and 0. As I read in the most of the resources, it is good to have data in the range of [-1, +1] or [0, 1]. So I thought I don't need any preprocessing. But when I run SVM and decision tree classifiers from scikit-learn, I got 100% accuracy using cross-validation with 10 folds. However the classification accuracy seems to decrease as I perform more iterations.

I am collecting these datas from a Kinect device which gives me angles and positions of the certain joints of the human body. Because of hardware faults I am sure that there are noise on data. So getting 100% is almost impossible.

My dataset is avaiable [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0cfkz96lr3rpkz/DatasetPerson1.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Are you sure there is no bugs in the code? The 100% accuracy on Cross Validation doesn't seem plausible. You may consider checking for overfitting, but again - you should see it on CV. Also: what are the classes? Maybe the classes are directly related to your features, so there is nothing to learn because the relation is "obvious"?

Comment: How is the label distribution over the data set? (How many of the 1175 examples are labeled with 0 / with 1)

Comment: Sharing your data set alone is not enough. The preferred way to get help on _StackExchange_ sites, such as _Cross Validated_ and _StackOverflow_, is to create a **minimal reproducible example** (aka **minimal working example**). If you cannot do that, at least, provide essential parts of your code, which produces the result in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your results:

```
> clf = svm.SVC()
> scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, Y, cv=10)
```

I didn't get perfect out of fold classification, but close:

```
> print(scores)
array([ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.99152542,  1.        ,
        1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ])
```

It's not very easy to figure out what's going on with a support vector machine, so I fit a decision tree to your data:

```
> tre = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
> tre.fit(X, Y)
```

The tree is a prefect classifier on the training data:

```
> sum(abs(tre.predict(X) - Y))
0
```

Turns out this tree is pretty simple:

[image]

It looks like the third column in your data (the one named `Z`) is a perfect separator. This is easily confirmed with a scatterplot:

[image]

Comment: I had the same tree with you which act lıke the maın decısıon maker. It seems that this dataset doesn't require a ML classıfıer at all. A simple if rule will do the job(wıth correct threshold), but it was good to understand this situation since I have plenty of this kind of dataset that I need to see if this situation is exist. So the way you did really help me. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the classifier (the tree) still told you something useful about the shape of your data, and that's a big part of learning.  Since you feel your question has been addressed, could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, my God, I came across the same issue. Maybe my answer is not the best answer for you, but it may help other people.

Here is my code with `Scikit-Learn`

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=10)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

And I got 100% accuracy score.

However, when I got the `feature_importances_` of `clf`, and I found the tag column was in `X` which should be removed from `X`, after removing the tag column from `X`, the accuracy was 89%.

So, my suggestion is after you built a model, check the parameters in it, for example `feature_importances_` etc. Good luck!